# How to Edit Contact Photo

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-contacts

I'm wanting to use Kotlin to update a contact with a new Bitmap `bmp` as a profile picture.  I found documentation for [editing contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data#EditContact), but I can't find a field on the intents page for changing the photo.  Any stack overflow solutions I found all involve strange ways of updating it, even though the developer page encourages using intents.  What's the best way to change contact photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never use bmp, it's such a huge file you don't want to put bmp photos in any database.

So, now to insert a **new** picture to a specific raw-contact, and assuming you have some standard picture file (jpeg/png) on hand, you do this:

```
val rawContactPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, yourRawContactId), // note that this must be a RAW-contact-id, not a contact-id
    RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_DIRECTORY
) // this is the url the represents a RawContact picture

try {
    val bytes = yourPictureFile.toByteArray() // get a byte array from your pic
    val fd = context.contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(rawContactPhotoUri, "rw")
    val os = fd?.createOutputStream()
    os?.write(bytes)
    os?.close()
    fd?.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify: I wasn't implying that I wanted to save the whole bmp, just that the variable was named "bmp."  I found this solution from another post recently and was able to use it, so I'll check this answer.